# How to fetch web table data using REST on button click.

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, rest, asp.net-mvc-4

I am fairly new to Visual studio. When I tried researching about how to use REST with C#, I found we should be selecting **MVC4 Web Application** on the new project list. Though I have already installed ASP.NET Web development from Visual Studio installed, MVC4 Web application option is not visible.
[image]
[image]
Is there any other way to fetch HTML web table elements using REST. Can we do it using web forms and not MVC4? Also, if any blog link can be provided which helps beginners in learning to develop web pages which can fetch data from other websites on button click using REST it will be appreciated.

Comment: Did you do some research on this title `How to use REST in WebForms with C#` ?

Comment: Just chose asp.net core webapplication. Afterwards the next step will ask you what kind of webapplication. It sounds like you want a normal webapplication with MVC. You can chose this option on the next screen. Then google for aps net core HttpClient

Comment: You need to learn how to use REST then you'll learn everything, the question and the images have nothing to do with REST.

Comment: Why would you choose MVC 4? It was replaced with MVC 5, and is now being replaced with MVC Core.  And we generally use Web API to make a REST API, though in MVC Core they are merged.

Answer (score 1):

You can send requests to an existing API using HttpClient, regardless of your project type (MVC, WebForms).

Microsoft's documentation provides a detailed explanation on how to do so: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/calling-a-web-api-from-a-net-client

The linked page makes use of a console application, but the code related to the HttpClient initialization and requests should work on both MVC and WebForms applications, provided that the correct libraries are included (as explained in the linked documentation).